# Can you coerce <object> tag so it issues POST instead of GET?

Tags: html, post, svg, asp-classic, get

I'm using an ASP classic app to create HTML `<table>...<td>` cells with SVG drawings encapsulated in an `<object>` tag, which works fine.  Here is what the `<object>` looks like:

`<object data="http://myserver.com/foo.asp?svgdata=data/bar.xml" type="image/svg+xml" border="1">Browser unsupported</object>`

When the page loads, `<object>` issues a GET to the server (and ASP), with a parameter value in its data= parameter.  My challenge is I'd like to create the svgdata= argument on the fly, and send a lengthy data payload in it to the server.  So I'm hoping I could use POST to do so, since GET is size-restricted.

Is there a way to coerce the `<object>` to issue POST instead of GET?  Assuming I could navigate the particularities of passing a correctly constructed svgdata= attribute.

Note, the final form of this is a pure HTML + SVG document in the browser DOM, it's not a Form or interactive otherwise.

Thank you, Stackoverflow readers!

Comment: Why not issue an XMLHttpRequest, get the data and then plug that into the object as a data URL?

Comment: I was thinking about that Robert, but the challenge is the pre-processing that yields the `object` is in XSLT, so maybe I could XMLHttpRequest PUT or maybe server-side JScript, and write a data snippet that way.  Thanks for considering.  I was just thinking it'd be cleaner to create some data in XSLT and pass it as a URL argument--if the size wasn't bigger than 2048.